# Planned event is shown outside the event borders in fullcalendar 4.3.1 in resourceTimelineWeek view with black eventTextColor

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I use fullcalender 4.3.1 to show events in the resourceTimelineWeek.

I show the start time and the end time. When the `eventTextColor` is **not** white and the event duration is very small it will show the end time ouside the border of the event.

I can simulate this in a codepen example shown on https://codepen.io/dreamflying/pen/jRoPWB.

When I add

```
eventTextColor: '#000000', displayEventTime: true, displayEventEnd: true,
```

after `editable: true,` in the js-tab you see all the text in black.

When you make an event small enough you see the text outside the borders which is a little weird in a complete calendar.

Screendump from Codepen:

[image]

Comment: Looks like it's probably a bug in fullCalendar. I made a CodePen which reduced it down to a much more minimal example, to be sure that nothing else was interfering or causing it. Changing the text colour and adding the event start time is sufficient, if the event is small enough. See here: https://codepen.io/ADyson82/pen/RwNpbrK . Anyway we cannot really help here with problems with the source code of fullCalendar, you may want to consider raising a [bug report](https://fullcalendar.io/reporting-bugs) instead.